# How to pass multiple string vectors of different lengths to Mapply

Tags: r, plyr, lapply, gtrendsr

The R package gtrendsr will return search data for a specific search term and date range. For example, the following arguments passed to the gtrends function will return to your console a list of detailed Google Search query data for NHL and NFL between January 2010 and April 3rd 2010.
If I want to return search by day for longer than 90 days, I have to pass another 90 day time window.

```
gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time = "2010-01-01 2010-04-03")
```

How would I write code to pass the search term as a vector of strings and the time ranges as a vector of strings. The goal would be to return data for each search term all of the time ranges.
Here is my best attempt so far:

```
 SportTerm <-c("NHL","NFL") 

TimeRange <-c("2010-01-01 2010-04-03","2010-04-04 2010-06-04")
```

I attempted to use lapply to see if I could return some data but to no avail.

```
DataDF <-as.data.frame(cbind(SportTerm,TimeRange)) 
GQVData<-lapply(DataDF, function(x){gtrendsR::gtrends(x[1], time = x[2])})
```

Not surprising, I get an error.

```
Error: is.vector(keyword) is not TRUE
```

There are several issues. One I donot know how to pass the vector of time range strings as arguments to the gtrends function. Second, even if I did, I would want for each term, the function to pull searches for both time ranges.
thanks for any wisdom.

Comment: try: `lapply(TimeRange, function(x) gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time =x)`

Comment: @missuse this solved the problem. I will try to check answered.

Comment: I was wrong it does not exactly solve the problem but it gets me closer to a solution. For whatever reason lapply only reads the first value of the vector TimeRange

Comment: When I try it: `z <- lapply(TimeRange, function(x) gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time =x)` I receive a list `z` with two elements `z[[1]]` and `z[[2]]` one has results for `TimeRange[1]` and the other for `TimeRange[2]`. When I run separate calls  `z1 = gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time = "2010-01-01 2010-04-03")` and `z2 = gtrends(c("NHL", "NFL"), time = "2010-04-04 2010-06-04")`. And do `z1$interest_over_time == z[[1]]$interest_over_time`
`z2$interest_over_time == z[[2]]$interest_over_time` I get all T values